# iPhone APP delegate alloc warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I see this output in allocations tool(one of too many warnings) Can anyone tell me what is going bad here? something with the UIImage and something very wrong with how I create/use navigation controller

[image]

And this is my category for imageview in APP_CATEGORIeS class import

```
@implementation UIImage(APP)
+(UIImage *) APP_IMAGE_BCKGROUND {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bckPhone" ofType:@"png"];
return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfResolutionIndependentFile:path]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a `UIImage` in a past view that wasn't released that's causing dirty leak. Make sure your view transitions are smooth (allocations wise).

On a separate note, if you're setting two different `anImageView` images and it's retained in another class then Xcode and the compiler *might* not be catching it and warning you, however that'll do nasty things when the code is executed.

Comment: also what you mean by "setting two different anImageView images and it's retained in another class "